# Store data for songs MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm storing a huge set of songs in a MySQL database. This is what I store in the 'songs' table:

```
CREATE TABLE `songs` (
  `song_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `song_artist` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `song_track` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `song_mix` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `song_title` text NOT NULL,
  `song_hash` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `song_addtime` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `song_source` text NOT NULL,
  `song_file` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`song_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1857 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now I'd like to keep track of how many plays each song has, and other song-specific data that relates to the song. I don't want to keep adding fields to the 'songs' table for this. How can I store song related data a more efficient way? What's the best practice here?

Comment: What you mean by "other song-specific data" will determine the best practice.

Comment: I don't see why would you create another table instead of adding a few more fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a 1 to 1 relationship, you should add it to the songs table. Nothing wrong with adding more fields to the table when the relationship calls for that. You could then use SQL to increment the field on each play.

Another approach could be used if, say, you want to keep track of how many times a particular user has played the song. You could create a relationship table that has `song_id, user_id, plays` as fields (song_id and user_id would form a composite key).

Depending on what you mean by

> song-specific data

will determine how the schema should be modified.